# Simple example of adding menu item to code editor’s popup menu in C++ builder

Tags: c++, c++builder

I need to add item to code editor’s popup menu in C++ builder 6. Where I can find simple example?
I found description of open api, found some delphi-code:

```
TPopupMenu(editorServices.TopView.GetEditWindow.Form.FindComponent('EditorLocalMenu'));
```

But no one example for adding code editor’s popup menu element. In demos only adding to Main Menu (into Help)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try first with this document for Delphi:

[Extending the Delphi IDE](https://www.embarcadero.com/images/dm/technical-papers/extending-the-delphi-ide.pdf)

Pay attention to the chapter titled "ADDING AN IDE EDITOR CONTEXT MENU ITEM AND GRABBING THE SELECTED TEXT"

Writing the C++ IDE's extension is well described in 
[OTA Template](http://www.davidghoyle.co.uk/WordPress/?page_id=1202) on [Dave's Development Blog](http://www.davidghoyle.co.uk/WordPress/).